# How to VBA MAilto all emails in a colum

Tags: excel, mailto, vba

Hi I have all my clients email address in row A on my excel sheet Named "Email". I have created the code below so that a box pops up when I press a bottom on the sheet and I can type the subject, and a few body lines. I want to be able to send the same message to all my client. IE for promotion or if we had to shut the office unexpectedly ect. Can any one help please?

```
Private Sub CommandButtonSend_Click()


Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Body1, Email_Body2, Email_Sig,         Email_Twitter As String
Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant

Dim emailrange As Range, cell As Range

Dim Email_Send_To As String


Set emailrange = Worksheets("Email").Range("A2:A4")

For Each cell In emailrange
Email_Send_To = Email_Send_To & "j" & cell.Value
Next
Email_Send_To = Mid(Email_Send_To, 2)
 On Error Resume Next

Email_Subject = UserFormTemplate.TextBoxSubject.Text


Email_Send_From = "shaunha@coversure.co.uk"


Email_Body1 = UserFormTemplate.TextBoxLine1.Text
Email_Body2 = UserFormTemplate.TextBoxLine2.Text

Email_Sig = UserFormTemplate.TextBoxSig.Text

Email_Twitter = UserFormTemplate.TextBoxTwitter.Text



On Error GoTo debugs
Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
With Mail_Single
.Subject = Email_Subject
.To = Email_Send_To
.cc = Email_Cc
.BCC = Email_Bcc
.Body = Email_Body1 & vbNewLine & Email_Body2 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine &     "Shaun Harrison  Insurance Consultant" & vbNewLine & "Tel: 0800 308 1022 /  shaunha@coversure.co.uk" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Email_Twitter
.send
End With
debugs:
If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description
End
End Sub
```

Comment: what exactly in this code is not working?

Answer (score -2):

```
Sub SendySend()

With ActiveSheet
    EndRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

RowCount = 4

For XCount = 4 To EndRow

 Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Dim olmail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    If Range("D" & RowCount).Value = "Yes" Then
        olmail.To = Range("A" & RowCount).Value
        olmail.Subject = Range("B" & RowCount).Value
        olmail.Body = Range("C" & RowCount).Value
        olmail.Send
    Else
        DontSend = 1 'This Doesn't do anything at all, it's just for clarity
    End If


RowCount = RowCount + 1

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I downvoted because how does this *really* the OP in question? It basically is the same code he has written, except his is more personalized to his needs, and yours is personalized in way that suited your needs at one point, and you don't explain what may or may not be relevant. It also does not explain the difference between early and late binding, where you use early and he uses late.

Comment: Fair comment, I thought it may help and (as you correctly pointed out) I had the old code handy from a previous project.